# How to get Pay Now URL with custom order status in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to get the URL from where the customer can directly pay for their Invoice and also it should work with `wc-cancelled` and `wc-transaction-declined` (*custom order status*).

**My Solution**
What I'm doing now is created a custom page with my custom get parameters and processing the whole Payment Process as Documentation in Gateway provider Website.

**My Problem**
But the problem is whenever they update their doc file and plugin I also have to update my code; but if I get the *Pay Now* URL then WooCommerce and Gateway Plugin will take care of it.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got the solution in WooCommerce `templates/emails/customer-invoice.php` file.  The function that I was looking for is `get_checkout_payment_url()`.

Usage

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$pay_now_url = esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() );
echo $pay_now_url; //http://example.com/checkout/order-pay/{order_id}?pay_for_order=true&key={order_key}
//http://example.com will be site_url and protocol will depending upon SSL checkout WooCommerce setting.
```

But this url only works with `pending`, `failed` order status; So I used filter `woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment`

```
if (!function_exists('filter_woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment')) {
    //http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderneeds_payment/
    //http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment/
    // define the woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment callback 
    function filter_woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment( $array, $instance ) {
        $my_order_status = array('cancelled', 'transaction-declined');
        return array_merge($array, $my_order_status);
    }
    // add the filter 
    add_filter('woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', 'filter_woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', 10, 2);
}
```

*^^ I added this in my active theme's `functions.php` file.*

---

Reference:

- [get_checkout_payment_url()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_checkout_payment_url)
- [wc_abstract_orderneeds_payment](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderneeds_payment/)
- [woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment/)

Comment: This is very useful… nice shot :)

Comment: thanks @LoicTheAztec, I had struggle for this, so thought to contribute this in SO, so that someone else will get benefited.

Comment: Need a shortcode can provide the pay-order link, example:
https://domaincom/checkout/order-pay/9374/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_jNNTl1X5nYV9U
Have some idea how can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get url with below code but it will work for wc-pending status order only, with the help of order_id or post_id

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
echo $pay_now_url = $order->get_checkout_payment_url();
```

Comment: Hi Vivekanand, yes that's true, please check the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40880539/5019802) and it is always recommended to use the native method. Because if WooCommerce change there logic of URL then you have to do that same for your code. But if you are using the native method then WooCommerce will handle that.

Comment: Hi @RaunakGupta, I updated answer.