# Woocommerce: Place order, but accept payment later?

Tags: woocommerce

Step 1: My WooCommerce shop is attached to a warehouse. I need customers to add products to cart, and then to place their order without making any payment or selecting any shipping.

Next, someone from my warehouse receives the order, and makes edits to the order, and then manually adds a shipping cost to the total invoice.

Step 2: The updated order is then sent back to the customer notifying them of the total cost of the order and then asks the customer to make payment via credit cart or bank transfer.

What I have done so far:

- I have configured Step 1 to work correctly - using cheque as Gateway method.  What I cannot do is Step 2, accept Payment via a different gateway,
- Plugin: WooCommerce Purchase Order Gateway, but that doesn't allow for payment to be captured via WooCommerce later on

What's the best practice here?

Comment: You can send a mail to the customer with a *Pay Now* link. check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40880509/5019802) as how to get that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using WooCommerce Request a Quote plugin, and configuring it to replace the "Add to Cart" button.

Once the Quote list has been submitted, someone from my end confirms the order and uses the Order's Action menu to send Customer Invoice which provides a hyperlink back to the payment gateway: Paypal, Credit Card, Direct Deposit etc.

Comment: Could you possibly post a link to the plug-in you've used? The functionality you're describing is exactly what I'm looking for. There's multiple with (roughly) that name, making me feel a bit lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking for same feature, [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-invoice-gateway/) helped me. but it allow you to send your client invoice